# Query results in "Object not found"

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

```
 iQuery := TFDQuery.Create( AConnection );
 iQuery.Connection := AConnection;
 iQuery.SQL.Add( 'Select I.Clino, I.Date, I.Type, I.Cash, I.Checke, I.Card, I.Acct, ' );
 iQuery.SQL.Add( 'I.ROA, I.Charges, I.Invno, I.LaterPaid, I.Station, ' );
 iQuery.SQL.Add( 'I.Tax, I.Discount, I.ToBePaid, I.Time, I.ClinCode, I.Clinno, C.LastName, C.Firstname ' );
 iQuery.SQL.Add( 'from Invoice I join Client C on I.Clino = C.Clino ' );
 iQuery.SQL.Add( 'where I.Date = :D order by I.Invno' );
 iQuery.ParamByName('D').AsDate := dDate;
 iQuery.IndexFieldNames := 'Invno';
 iQuery.IndexesActive := true;
 iQuery.DetailFields := 'Invno';
 iQuery.Open;

 rQuery := TFDQuery.Create( AConnection );
 rQuery.Connection := AConnection;
 rQuery.SQL.Add( 'Select R.Invno, R.Related, R.Entry, P.Patient, R.Charge, R.Discount, R.Tax, R.ClinCode' );
 rQuery.SQL.Add( 'from Records R' );
 rQuery.SQL.Add( 'join Patient P on P.Patno = R.Patno' );
 rQuery.SQL.Add( 'where R.SSDO = true' );
 rQuery.SQL.Add( 'order by R.Related' );
 rQuery.IndexFieldNames := 'Invno';
 rQuery.IndexName := 'Invno';
 rQuery.IndexesActive := true;
 rQuery.MasterFields := 'Invno';
 rQuery.MasterSource := srcInv;
 rQuery.Open;
```

The RECORDS table (rQuery) contains about 3M records.  This query should yield about a dozen of these records.  Records has an index "Invno( invno )".  When I execute this code I get the following error:

[FireDAC][DatS]-2.  Object [Invno] is not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Spyke

Comment: In real code, I trust you use `try..finally` blocks to protect your resources.

Comment: I don't.  Where should I use it in this case?

Comment: `rQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil) try {use rQuery} finally rQuery.Free; end` Well, not only for `rQuery`, but for all your object instances.

Comment: Did you try you SQL request my mySQL query tool to verify it is OK?

Comment: Why are you setting IndexesActive, IndexFieldNames and MasterSource/MasterFields before opening the query?